# sort of autoincrement in map

Tags: c++, stl

I have this code and what I want to achieve is that I want to actually perform increment on `c` if and only if I am actually inserting into map, I studied map's operator[], but didn't get it to work as I wanted. Is there any simple way how to do it? Or I have to search for key before inserting everytimme and if I find nothing only then increment and insert

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

int main ()
{
  std::map<std::string,int> mymap;
  int cnt = 0;
  int h = -1;

  mymap.insert(std::pair<std::string, int>("GBP", cnt++));
  mymap.insert(std::pair<std::string, int>("EUR", cnt++));
  mymap.insert(std::pair<std::string, int>("USD", cnt++));
  mymap.insert(std::pair<std::string, int>("GBP", cnt++));
  mymap.insert(std::pair<std::string, int>("GBP", cnt++));
  mymap.insert(std::pair<std::string, int>("GBP", cnt++));
  mymap.insert(std::pair<std::string, int>("CAD", cnt++));
  mymap.insert(std::pair<std::string, int>("GBP", cnt++));

  std::cout << cnt << std::endl;

for(const auto & v : mymap)
  std::cout << v.first << " " << v.second << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

result would be gbp 0, eur 1, usd 2, cad 4 (not cad 6)

Comment: YourMap[YourKey]++ This code increment the value if key exists or creates the key with value = 1 (I am not sure if 0) if key doesn't exist. Hope it helps

Comment: Why not just use `mymap.size()` as the second part of the pair?

Comment: hehe using map.size() this is actually so smart! thank you

Comment: I still don't get it. You want `cnt` to increment, but if and only if the insert was actually a real insert, is that right ? If that is the case, why not just use iterator/bool pair returned from the `insert` call and only increment `cnt` if the latter is `true`? Edit: ok. I see, you just want the `second` of each pair to be a count-of-key-inserts. Got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`insert` returns a `pair` whose `first` is an iterator to the element that was inserted (not interesting here) and whose `second` is a `bool` that tells you whether the element was actually added.

So, you could check that:

```
if(mymap.insert(std::pair<std::string, int>("GBP", cnt)).second)
    cnt++;
if(mymap.insert(std::pair<std::string, int>("EUR", cnt)).second)
    cnt++;
// and so on.
```

In this particular case, though, you can use `mymap.size()` as the count:

```
mymap.insert(std::pair<std::string, int>("GBP", mymap.size()));
mymap.insert(std::pair<std::string, int>("EUR", mymap.size()));
// and so on.
```

since the map's size will increase by 1 whenever an element is inserted.